# Is "is" elided in the sentence?

Tags: elision

The original sentence:

> Unless suitable on other grounds oilfields have not become industrial
>   regions; on the contrary the oil industry is marked by a certain
>   amount of smell and an element of danger, hence the siting of
>   refineries at a distance from population centres.

Is there an "is" in the last part if fully spelled out?

> Unless suitable on other grounds oilfields have not become industrial
>   regions; on the contrary the oil industry is marked by a certain
>   amount of smell and an element of danger, hence the siting of
>   refineries **[is]** at a distance from population centres.

Comment: Yes, semantically a verbless clause ("the refineries are sited at a distance from population centres"), but it's parsed as noun phrase with "siting" as head.

Comment: The phrase "on the contrary" is usually followed by a comma.

Answer (score 1):

The original sentence is complete. "Hence" or "thus" is frequently followed by simply describing a situation as a noun or a noun clause, like

```
The time will run out soon; hence, the problem.
```

or

```
I had time to spend; hence, my presence here.
```

or, in this case:

```
there is smell; hence, the siting at a certain location.
```

Answer (score -1):

Hence (adverb) tends to imply the existence of a verb. But I'm not sure what verb is elided. Everything is elided. That paragraph is pure cuttlefish ink. I would find the person who wrote it and, if legal in your juristiction, challenge them to mutual combat.